# Property that can be gotten and set by CSS (a variable?)

Tags: html, css, properties, html-table

I'm trying to make a CSS only zebra table which is compatible with IE 7.

I tried this:

```
.zebra {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.zebra tr:first-child {
    background-color: #7BCC70;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.zebra tr[valign=top] + tr {
    color: #EEE;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.zebra tr[valign=bottom] + tr {
    color: #7BCC70;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

The vertical-align doesn't affect anything, because of the first rule. I set the color of the first tr to color1 and vertical-align to indicator1. Then I try to get the vertical align of the tr by using valign, but that doesn't work. vertical-align isn't valign, just like bgcolor isn't background-color. I can get valign, but I can't set it. I can set vertical-align, but I can't get it through CSS. Can you think of something that can be set and gotten in CSS?

.zebra is the table, which is regular:

```
<table class="zebra" border="0">
<tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color: white;">
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You asked for it.

Comment: Please show the html portion of code that you're trying to apply styles to.  It's a bit unclear as to exactly what you're trying to do here. The selectors you're using are for html attributes, not CSS.

Comment: "I can get valign, but I can't set it." How do U set it?

Comment: @Shawn: imagine valign and vertical-align were the same. What would you get? A zebra table.

Comment: CSS isn't a programming language. You may get somewhere with Sass/SCSS or LESS...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think I found it. I always search around for a century, ask it and find it five minutes later.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

It's a kind of cheating, I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure IE7 doesn't support a good way of selecting odd or even rows within a table with a dynamic number of rows, without you marking them up as such:

```
tr.odd { background-color:#7bcc70; }
tr.even { background-color:#eee; }

<table>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or, you could use a jQuery script to do the work for you, like mentioned here: http://masterdev.dyndns.dk/dev/16.html

Personally, I use this (for modern browsers):

```
.zebra tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #7bcc70; }
.zebra tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #eee; }

<table class="zebra">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that this does not require you to mark-up each row.  I fall back to a normal (non-zebra) table for older browsers.  With my project, however, I am permitted some level of graceful degradation.

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to answer with - to make this work in IE7 you'll need to do it as Duffman described.